# How can I calculate distance based on altitude and glideslope angle?

Tags: navigation, general-aviation

How do I calculate the distance to touchdown when the glideslope angle is different from 3°? For example, you are 670ft AGL on a 3.2° glideslope approach; what do I change in the formula to calculate the distance?

Comment: Which formula are you referring to?

Comment: How about doing it for 3° then subtracting 7% (a close approximation of .2)?

Comment: @Simon subtracting 7% is quite fair (see also my answer on approximation).

Answer (score 2):

Since the 1 in 60 rule of thumb yields a solution of 300 feet for every NM from the touchdown point for a 3 degree slope, use 320 feet for a 3.2 degree slope.  So 670ft, gives you a nadgers whisker over 2 nm.

To be a little more precise, 2.09375 nm ($\frac{670}{320}$)

Comment: DeltaWhisky, not sure why your edit disappeared but I must point out that a nadgers whisker has a very precise meaning in general aviation.  A badgers whisker is quite different, so I've edited it back.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you determine that a 3.2 degree slope needs a 320 ft/NM descent?  Is there a rule of thumb that you are using to determine that?

Comment: As you say. it's just an approximation but 300ft per NM at 3 degrees is good enough for GA.  It's an extension of the 1 in 60 rule. So, you can say 100ft per degree.  3.2 degrees is therefore 320 ft.

Answer (score 2):

The $300ft/NM$ used to calculate your height above the runway at a particular distance is just an approximation that is easy to remember, and is close enough for our purposes.

If you want a more exact number, you can use some trigonometry:

$$\tan(3)=\frac{xft}{6,076ft/NM}=318ft/NM$$

(the "real" number).

For 3.2 degrees, it would be:

$$\tan(3.2)=\frac{xft}{6,076 ft/NM}=340ft/NM$$

So if you want to know the appropriate altitude for, say a 3 mile final on a 3.2 degree glideslope, it would be:

$$Runway~Touchdown~Elevation+340ft/NM\times3NM=TDE+1,020ft$$

In your specific example where you already know the altitude and want to know when to start the descent, the answer would be $2NM$:

$$\frac{670ft}{340ft/NM}=2.0NM$$

($1.97$ if you want to be REALLY exact.)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you don't have a calculator at hand (yeah, I know...):

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28670ft%29/Tan%5B3.2%C2%B0%5D%20in%20nautical%20miles) returns (unsurprisingly): 1.97nm (and lot of other entertaining info).

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Sidenote: Because [$\tan(\alpha)\approx\alpha~for~small~\alpha$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation), you can use a simple linear approximation in this case. Your new glide distance will be more or less $\frac{3}{3.2}=\frac{15}{16}=0.9375$ times the original one.

Comment: Or paste this into google.

670 ft/tan(3.2 degrees) to nautical miles

Answer (score 1):

[image]

---

$$tan(3.2)=\frac{670}{a}$$
$$\frac{670}{\tan(3.2)}=a$$

$$a=11,983ft$$
$$11,983ft=1.97NM$$

Answer (score 0):

Since we all agree that a 3.2°GS give us 340'/nm, I suggest that you take your FAA, subtract by the TCH elevatin and divide by 340, the result is the distance to touchdown

Answer (score -4):

Thanks to all for answers. The $\frac{1.97}{96}$ was not correct.

This is how you should do it:

$$3.2=\frac{670ft\times60}{3.2}=12,562ft=2.066NM$$

Comment: The 1.97 nm is the precise value. The rule of thumb overestimates the value slightly.

Comment: As Jan says, 1.97 is the actual correct mathematical value.  Your answer does not **accurately** answer the question as you originally asked it....